# Is it possible to efficiently find the index of a dictionary item in Python by key?

Tags: python, dictionary

As of Python 3.7, dictionaries are guarantueed to keep insertion order. According to the original proposal for the change of memory layout (https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2012-December/123028.html), an `indices` list stores the index of each value, indexed by the key hash. Therefore, it should be possible to efficiently retrieve an index of an item in the dictionary by its key. However, there seems to be no method for doing that. The only way I can think of is the following:

```py
a = {}
a[1] = "b"
a[0] = "a"
a[2] = "c"
list(a).index(0) # returns 1
```

However, this is very inefficient. Do I have to use a library with a custom dictionary implementation or is there a way to access the internal CPython representation of a dictionary?

Comment: Without improving on the linear asymptotic time complexity, you could do: `next(i for i, k in enumerate(a) if k == 0)`. At least, you get O(1) space and short-circuit.

Comment: Given a continuous sequence of items like A, B, C, D, E, F. I want to know how long the continuous part at the end is when certain items are removed. For example, if D is removed, the continuous part is E, F. For this, I want to use a dictionary as a set, containg all items as keys. I also want to keep track of the first index of the continuous part, starting at 0. If D is removed, I get the index of it (4), and set the first index of the continuous part to 4 (since D is removed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to perform this operation on the same dictionary multiple times (without changing its content), you could create an indexing dictionary for the keys and use that to get the index:

```
a = {1:"b", 0:"a", 2:"c"}
ia = {k:i for i,k in enumerate(a)}

print(ia[0]) # 1
```

If you don't want a separate dictionary, you could store the indexes along with the values in tuples:

```
a = {1:"b", 0:"a", 2:"c"}
a = {k:(i,v) for i,(k,v) in enumerate(a.items())}

print(a)
{1: (0, 'b'), 0: (1, 'a'), 2: (2, 'c')}


index,value = a[0]
print(index) # 1
```

Otherwise some form of sequential search will probably be your only option:

```
i = next(i for i,k in enumerate(a) if k=0)
```

Comment: Tracking it redundantely is my best option, I guess. Thanks!